# Javascript Timestamp, if 10 minutes go by.

Tags: javascript, date, time

I'm trying to figure out if 10 minutes go by, then an action happens. Right now all I have is this, I don't understand the timestamp too well. Such as 1370246236916...Where is the hour, day, year and minutes or seconds etc.

```
var ten_mins = new Date().getTime();
var time = data_base_time;
var time_to_ago = time - new Date().getTime()+100000;

if( time >= time_to_ago){
   //Ten minutes went by
}
```

Comment: getTime returns milliseconds since 1970-01-01, if you want 10 minutes, the constant should be 10*60*1000 = 600000 milliseconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The getTime() method returns the number of milliseconds between midnight of January 1, 1970 and the specified date.

```
var current = new Date().getTime();
var ten_minutes_from_now = new Date().getTime() + 600000;

if(ten_minutes_from_now >= current) window.alert('Ten minutes have passed');
```

Comment: Unless the JavaScript takes 10 minutes to execute, the `alert` will never occur ;)

Comment: @BenM I know, but I figured his code was just an example, so it was based on that.

Comment: Well, I'm getting data from a real time database, and as the user checks the update, it would respond with how minutes remaining. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Why not use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout):

```
window.setTimeout(function() {  
    // 10 minutes have gone by. Execute a function here.
}, 600000);
```

Answer (score 0):

timeStamp event property returns the number of in milliseconds since midnight of January 1, 1970

Mon, 03 Jun 2013 07:57:16 GMT means 1370246236916 milliseconds from January 1, 1970.